# Ruby split on numbers vs letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to split the following string on letters:

```
1234B
```

There are always only ever 4 digits and one letter. I just want to split those out.

Here is my attempt, I think I have the method right and the regex matches the number but I dont think my syntax or my regex is pertinent to the problem Im attempting to solve.

```
"1234A".split(/^\d{4}/)
```

Comment: So, you want to split on letters. Why are you instead splitting on "not digits"? There are other character classes, you know. Punctuation and stuff like that :)

Comment: Also, define what you are meaning by "split". Post expected result of the operation on that input.

Comment: can you gave an example of what do you want as result of that spiting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are *always* 4 digits and 1 letter, there's no need to use regular expressions to split the string. Just do this:

```
str = "1234A"
digits,letter = str[0..3],str[4]
```

Answer (score 20):

What you want is not clear, but a general solution to this kind of situation is:

```
"1234A".scan(/\d+|\D+/)
# => ["1234", "A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it purely from the perspective of splitting any string into groups of 4:

```
"1234A".scan(/.{1,4}/)
# => ["1234", "A"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another no-regex version:

```
str = "1234A"

str.chars.to_a.last # => "A"
str.chop            # => "1234"
```

Comment: Using `chars` then converting to an array is a convoluted way of doing this. What about `str[-1]`?

Comment: It looks like OP is having troubles with this (simple) problem - thats why I wanted to provide an answer that is more or less readable. For a ruby newcomer I consider `str.chars.to_a.last` to be more intention revealing than `str[-1]`. I don't think anyone can come up with a simpler answer than Alex, but IMHO it doesn't hurt to show that there are _many_ different ways to solve this.